# How do I enable extensions for gnome fedora 34

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

My system specs -

```
❯ neofetch                                                                                                                                                                                                                     12:33:48
ninan@fedora 
OS: Fedora 34 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
Host: ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401IU_GA401IU 1.0 
Kernel: 5.15.15-200.rog.fc34.x86_64 
Uptime: 40 mins 
Packages: 3012 (rpm), 3 (flatpak) 
Shell: bash 5.1.0 
Resolution: 2560x1440 
DE: GNOME 40.7 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Kripton 
Theme: Kripton [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: terminator 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 4900HS with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 3.000GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile 
GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Renoir 
Memory: 4666MiB / 15467MiB
```

When I try to install or enable arc menu or any gnome extension, nothing happens.
[image: Gnome tweaks]

Gnome tweaks show that user theme extension is not installed. I have already tried goign to https://extensions.gnome.org and enabling. But nothing gets enabled. I have also tried enabling from my terminal.

```
~ via  
❯ gnome-extensions list                                                                                                                                                                                                        12:43:16
appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com
apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
arcmenu@arcmenu.com
user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
background-logo@fedorahosted.org
launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com

~ via  
❯ gnome-extensions enable window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com                                                                                                                                                12:43:18


~ via  
❯ echo $status                                                                                                                                                                                                                 12:43:20
0

~ via  
❯ gnome-extensions info window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com                                                                                                                                                  12:43:22

window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
  Name: Window List
  Description: Display a window list at the bottom of the screen.
This extension is part of Classic Mode and is officially supported by GNOME. Please do not report bugs using the form below, use GNOME's GitLab instance instead.
  Path: /home/ninan/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
  URL: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions
  Version: 41
  State: INITIALIZED

~ via  
❯
```

How do I enable the extensions ?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting here is for theming the extensions' surface. To enable extensions as in applets, use the separate "Extensions" app.

But if you are in fact trying to theme extensions, install `shell-user-theme-extensions` from your package manager.

```
dnf -i shell-user-theme-extensions
```

But if it continues— well, it may be a bug. Report it on the bug tracking site of which I can not remember.

Hope this helps,

Mac Henni